# How to animate jQuery image transition by src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am making image transition by replacing the "src" in the image HTML tag

```
<img src="background0.jpg" alt="" id="bg">
```

The question is: How do I animate the transition, for example fading out the old picture and fading in the next or sliding right.

JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(function ($) {
    var images = [
            'background0.jpg',
            'background1.jpg',
            'background2.jpg',
            'background3.jpg'
        ],
        amountOfImages = images.length,
        tempR = 0,
        $bg = $('#bg');

    for (let i = 0; i < amountOfImages; i++) {
        var img = new Image(),src = images[i];
    }

    function fader(){
        let r = Math.floor(Math.random()*amountOfImages);
        $bg.attr('src', images[r]); //TODO: Animate the transition
        tempR = r;
    }
    fader();

    setInterval(fader, 5000);
});
```

Comment: you can try to use $bg.fadeIn(), but what you are trying to do inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery, you can do this, so that after the current image fades out, the function gets called to swap the image source

```
 function fader(){
     let r = Math.floor(Math.random()*amountOfImages);
     $('#bg').fadeOut(500, function(){
       $bg.attr('src', images[r]); //TODO: Animate the transition
       $('#bg').fadeIn(500);
     tempR = r;
    })
}
```